# Android widget blanking variables when configured to open the main app on click

Tags: java, android, mobile, widget

I am developing an app in Flutter with an associated widget. The widget's logic relies solely on the current day. Currently, it functions with a worker that runs continuously. However, I would like the app to open when clicking the widget. I attempted to achieve this by adding a button inside the widget associated with a PendingIntent. However, for some reason, after making this change, the values disappear from the widget and empty texts appear in their place. I have tried to figure out why this happens, but I do not understand what is causing it. Thank you.

this is the code of the android widget without the pendidng intent:

```
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetManager;
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetProvider;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.TypedValue;
import android.widget.RemoteViews;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.work.Constraints;
import androidx.work.NetworkType;
import androidx.work.PeriodicWorkRequest;
import androidx.work.WorkManager;
import androidx.work.Worker;
import androidx.work.WorkerParameters;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.Locale;

public class SimpleWidgetProvider extends AppWidgetProvider {

    @Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
        super.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);

        Constraints constraints = new Constraints.Builder()
                .setRequiredNetworkType(NetworkType.CONNECTED)
                .build();

        PeriodicWorkRequest workRequest = new PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder(
                UpdateWidgetWorker.class,
                30,
                TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                .setConstraints(constraints)
                .build();

        WorkManager.getInstance(context).enqueue(workRequest);
    }

    public static class UpdateWidgetWorker extends Worker {

        public UpdateWidgetWorker(
                @NonNull Context context,
                @NonNull WorkerParameters workerParams) {
            super(context, workerParams);
        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public Result doWork() {
            Context context = getApplicationContext();
            AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);

            int[] appWidgetIds = appWidgetManager.getAppWidgetIds(
                    new ComponentName(context, SimpleWidgetProvider.class));

            for (int appWidgetId : appWidgetIds) {
                updateWidget(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetId);
            }

            return Result.success();
        }

        private void updateWidget(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int appWidgetId) {
            RemoteViews widgetUpdateViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.simple_widget);

           DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
            int screenWidth = displayMetrics.widthPixels;
            int screenHeight = displayMetrics.heightPixels;

           int textSize;
            if (screenWidth <= 485 && screenHeight <= 805) {
                textSize = 18; 
            }

            SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
            String currentDate = dateFormat.format(new Date());

            int shouldShowZeroOne = checkSpecialDates(currentDate);

            SimpleDateFormat otroDate = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE", new Locale("es", "ES"));
            String otroWeek = otroDate.format(new Date());
            otroWeek = otroWeek.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + otroWeek.substring(1);

            widgetUpdateViews.setTextViewText(R.id.textViewOtro, otroWeek);

            if (shouldShowZeroOne == 5) {
                widgetUpdateViews.setTextViewText(R.id.textView, "8 - 9");
                widgetUpdateViews.setTextViewTextSize(R.id.textView, TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, textSize);

            }
            if (shouldShowZeroOne == 0) {
                widgetUpdateViews.setTextViewTextSize(R.id.textView, TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, (textSize - 6));
                widgetUpdateViews.setTextViewText(R.id.textView, "");

            }
            appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, widgetUpdateViews);
        }

        private int checkSpecialDates(String currentDate) {
 String[] targetDates89 = {
                    "2023-10-06"};
            for (String date : targetDates89) {
                if (currentDate.equals(date)) {
                    return 5;
                }
            }
            return 0;
        }

    }
}
```

This is the code of the widget layout simple_widget.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#55000000"> 

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/titleTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="car "
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFFFF"
        android:textStyle="bold" 
        android:alpha="0.8" 
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp" 
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp" /> 
        
          <TextView
        android:id="@+id/algo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=""
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFFFF"
        android:textStyle="bold" 
        android:alpha="0.8" 
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp" 
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp" /> 

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="0"
        android:textSize="40sp" 
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" 
        android:alpha="0.8" 
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp" 
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

            <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewOtro"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFFFF"
        android:alpha="0.8" 
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

I tried adding pending intents to open the flutter app to the widget and to buttons added to the widget, but every time I make this change, the values in the widget become permanently blank.